# How to on/off woocommerce filter with redux framework

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using this woocommerce filter in my function file

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

How can i get on/off system to this filter with redux framework. I already created Option in redux. But i am not sure how can i use redux option in function file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add redux global variable between funtion

```
  add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
        function redirect_to_checkout() {
         global $xpanel;   if ( isset( $xpanel['woo-option'] ) && $xpanel['woo-option'] == TRUE ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
        return $checkout_url;

        }
    }
```